# Zend Framework: Set Default Response Section

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I'm not 100% sure how to phrase this question so please help me if you can.

I have a system with modules that can be installed. I check if each module has a MenuController and if so I push an action onto the stack. The problem becomes that in each MenuController, if I don't use $this->render('index.phtml', 'menu'); then the output goes into the body. Is there some way that I can specify that the output for the menu controllers should go into the 'menu' section by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just extending Zend_Controller_Request_Http and adding methods for DefaultName().

Answer (score 0):

in MenuController use `$this->_helper->viewrenderer->setResponseSegment('sth');` in preDispatch() :)

Comment: This actually doesn't work as the viewRenderer state is reset with each controller init. I'm calling multiple MenuController(s), one for each module.

Comment: Predispatch method of controller is called before EVERY dispatching of the controller...

Comment: Yes, but I don't extend from a common base controller and the viewRenderer state gets reset after a plugin's preDispatch. I would have to put it in the preDispatch of every MenuController and that's more work than just passing it as a param.